# Will kext file come back after enabling SIP

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

So my mac kernal_task keep using 600%++ of my CPU usage when my Mac is plugged in, and thus i decided to delete the IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext by doing these steps:

- Enter Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal
- Disable SIP: csrutil disable
- Enter Single User Mode
- Delete the kext file

But will the kext file come back if i enable SIP again?
I'm currently using High Sierra but i have been doing this since Sierra
And i followed this guide https://www.davidschlachter.com/misc/kernel_task

Comment: Which version of OSX are you running? I imagine that could make a difference. Also, were you following any recommendations when you deleted the kext? If so, please link them.

Comment: Edited, thank you!

Comment: SIP/csrutil just stops you from deleting files/dirs in some protected directories. It does not have a way to restore files you have deleted. Personally I find SIP to not be that useful, but you can go ahead and enable it again.

Comment: I also find it not that useful, but having it enabled is better than nothing, thank you for your answer @lundman